# Extract / access XML file embedded in PDF

Tags: r, xml, pdf

I have a PDF with an embedded XML file. I want to access the embedded XML file in R.

One way to solve the problem manually would be to open the PDF file with Adobe Acrobat and save the embedded XML file from there manually (see [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/links-attachments-pdfs.html#open_save_or_delete_an_attachment)). The saved XML file could then be accessed in R using the [XML](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) package.

However, as I have to run this for numerous PDFs and the rest of the code is in R, I'm looking for a solution in R. The [pdftools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdftools/index.html) package doesn't seem to provide a solution, nor does [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) seem to be implemented for R.

Comment: I may have a solution - are you able to give a link to a sample pdf to test using Dropbox or similar?

Comment: @AllanCameron I can't share the original file as it contains sensitive data. I have found a sample file on [Github](https://github.com/aspose-pdf/Aspose.PDF-for-.NET/blob/master/Examples/Data/AsposePDF/Attachments/GetIndividualAttachment.pdf) - the attachment here is TXT, not XML, but the workflow should be the same.

Comment: essentially I have written a pdf library in R (actually in c++ with a nice R interface) that can obtain the compressed streams from pdf objects. For instance, the attached text file in the example pdf you linked was in object 6 of the pdf, and is just a short string, which I got by doing `get_object("sample.pdf"), 6)$stream` and which returned `[1] "Aspose.Pdf for .NET"`, which is correct according to github. Without seeing your own pdf, it will be difficult to advise you how to extract your xml. You're welcome to try yourself, of course - see https://github.com/AllanCameron/PDFR

Comment: Is embedding the same as attachment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `pdftools` has `pdf_attachments()` function. Using the example pdf file you provided:

```r
library(pdftools)

a<-pdftools::pdf_attachments("GetIndividualAttachment.pdf")

txt <- a[[1]]$data
txt
#>  [1] 41 73 70 6f 73 65 2e 50 64 66 20 66 6f 72 20 2e 4e 45 54

rawToChar(txt)
#> [1] "Aspose.Pdf for .NET"
```

You should be able to extract XML attachment in similar manner.

Comment: If the PDF has more than one file attached the way to access every file is changing "txt <- a[[x]]$data" where "x" is the index of each file attached?